# Upload image whit Selenium and Python on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, django, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a problem...

This is my code:

```
upimage = ActionChains(webdriver).move_to_element( webdriver.find_element_by_class_name("button"))
print ('open')
sleep(5)
upimage.send_keys("/home/user/Image/2.jpg")
print ('selected')
sleep(5)
```

it open popup for choose file and print "open"

after if print "selected" but not select and load any image!!!

Whats' wrong?

EDIT 1:

I try with:

```
upimage.send_keys("/home/user/Image/2.jpg").perform()
```

no effect!

EDIT 2

code:

```
upimage = ActionChains(webdriver).move_to_element( webdriver.find_element_by_class_name("button"))
upimage.send_keys("/home/user/Image/2.jpg").perform()
```

doesn't work!

Comment: What does 'after if print "selected" but not select and load any image!!!' mean? Are you trying to submit a form? This is quite confusing.

Comment: i use print to see if it run code until that point.... Ignore print, it not load image, what's wrong?

Comment: No form, I try to upload a photo in a website

Comment: Is there any text field of Id upload file like that?can you post the html content in your original post ?